# Finding the derivative of $ \cos(\arcsin x)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I study maths as a hobby. I am trying to find the derivative of $ \cos(\arcsin x)$

This is how I have been proceeding:

Let u = $\arcsin x$

Then $\sin u = x$

Differentiating:
\begin{align}
\cos u \frac{du}{dx} &= 1 \implies \frac{du}{dx} = \frac{1}{\cos u} \\[4pt]
\cos^2 u + \sin^2 u &= 1 \\[4pt]
\cos u &= \sqrt {1 - \sin^2 u} = \sqrt {1 - x^2}
\end{align}
But that is as far a I get.

The text book says the answer is $\frac{x}{\sqrt {1 - x^2}}$  but I cannot see how this is arrived at.

Comment: WolframAlpha obtains $-x/\sqrt{1-x^2}$, which is consistent with $\cos(\arcsin x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ for $-1<x<-1$. So the textbook answer seems off by a sign.

Comment: So based on your work for the derivative of arcsine (which is correct by the way) you should be able to get the correct answer using the chain rule. And yes, the answer you gave from the textbook is missing a negative sign.

Comment: Can be useful $$\cos \left(\arcsin x\right)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your notation, $x = \sin u$, we have $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\cos (\sin^{-1} x)\right] = -\sin (\sin^{-1} x) \cdot \frac{d}{dx} \left[ \sin^{-1} x \right] = -x \frac{d}{dx} \left[ \sin^{-1} x \right].$$  Since $$\frac{dx}{du} = \cos u,$$ we have $$\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{1}{\cos u} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \sin^2 u}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$$  Therefore, $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\cos(\sin^{-1} x)\right] = - \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$$

Comment: The approach is completely fine, but I would like to point out that $\cos u = \sqrt{1-\sin^2 u}$ only when $\cos$ is nonnegative, which works in this case since $u\in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. I'm bringing this up since OP seems to be self-taught and this might be a subtle point for them.

Comment: Since 2009, the ISO 80000-2 standard has specified solely the "arc" prefix for the inverse functions : Old habits die hard.

Comment: @Martin Hansen, well, the notation for trigonometric functions is a mess anyway. If $\sin^2x = (\sin x)^2$, $\sin^{-1}x$ should be $1/\sin x$, or if $\sin^{-1}$ is the inverse function, $\sin^2$ should be $\sin\circ \sin$. This is a general problem of never writing down multiplication in respect to which one is taking powers. Though, in my opinion, I agree that $\arcsin$ is better since by $\sin$ we usually mean a function defined on $\mathbb R$, which is not invertible.

Comment: @Ennar I only mentioned it because the OP seems to be self taught so there's no point them learning something out of date. The latest Edexcel A-Level and GCSE text books and exam papers are firmly "arc". (The OP's question is an A-Level question) The notation $\sin^{-1}$ is now considered to have no meaning. I suspect other exam boards have gone the same way but haven't checked. The Calculators sold in the UK are still with the old notation though so it is taking a long time to rumble through... (+1 if you can be bothered to update your answer !)

Comment: @Ennar I couldn't agree more. The notation $\sin^{-1}$ is so bizzare given that it is *not* true in general that $\sin^{-1}(\sin(x))=x$. Although we can restrict the domain of $\sin(x)$ to $-\frac{\pi}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, that means that we end up with a new function (which is occassionally denoted as $\operatorname{Sin}$ with a capital 'S'). What's more, $\arcsin(x)$ is such a pleasant notation: it's the arc whose sine is equal to $x$ !

Answer (score 2):

Let $y=\cos(u)=\cos(\arcsin x)$. You have correctly worked out that $du/dx$ is
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
$$
but you need to multiply this result by $dy/du$. The textbook's answer actually contains a sign error.

---

This result can be obtained more directly if you write the chain rule in Lagrange notation. If $y=f(g(x))$, then
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x) \, .
$$
Here, $f=\cos$ and $g=\arcsin$. Hence, $dy/dx$ equals
$$
-\sin(\arcsin(x)) \cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, ,
$$
which can be simplified further.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

The range of ArcSin is $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$, so the $\cos[$ArcSin$(x)]$ will be $\geq 0.$

Further, if $\theta = $ArcSin$(x)$, then $\cos(\theta)$ [which by the above statement will be non-negative] will be $\sqrt{1 - x^2}.$

Therefore, the question **immediately** reduces to computing

$$\frac{d}{dx} \sqrt{1 - x^2}.$$

Comment: You can use ``\arcsin`` to typeset things.